# how to update syslogins table in Sybase 11

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I wonder if it possible to update table syslogins for Sybase 11 database.
statement:

```
UPDATE syslogins SET name = 'aaa' WHERE name = 'bbb';
```

Leads to error: no permission.

I've read about preparation `sp_configure "allow update", 1;`
but there is no procedure `sp_configure` in Sybase 11 (it exists for Sybase 15+).

Is there any another workaround for the task?

Comment: Hi, all! Also I wonder why the first row of my question is lost!

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are using Sybase SQLAnywhere (based on the version number), but the procedures and tables you are trying to edit are part of Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise (ASE).

In [SQLAnywhere](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.0/sqlanywhere_en11/help_top_index.htm), syslogins is a view that pulls information from the `ISYS*` tables, but is only there to maintain [compatibility with T-SQL](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.0/dbreference_en11/views-s-3394202.html).